# Unable to change value of control programmatically while using useFieldArray in react hook forms and nextJS/reactJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

I am using react hook form in nextJS.
The requirment is to calculate and show the totalPrice and grantTotal in the form UI when user changes the values of quantity or price

This is part of a invoice genration application.

Though I am calling setValue, the field value is not dislayed for the totalPrice. What could be the issue here.

Following is the code snippet I tried.

**Component Source Code :**
fieldArray creation.

```
const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: 'transactionItems',
});
```

I am calculating and setting the totalPrice (grantTotal is not used timebeing) with the following code. Please note that totalPrice is also a registered field with rhf.

```
{fields.map((field, index) => {
    const setSubTotal = (index, quantity, rate) => {
    const amount = parseInt(quantity) * parseInt(rate);
    setValue(`transactionItems[${index}].totalPrice`, 100);
    field.totalPrice = 200;
    console.log('index,quantity, rate');
    console.log(index, quantity, rate);
    };

    return (...)
```

This is triggered in the onChange while registering the component.

```
<Grid item xs={4} sm={4} md={2}>
    <div>
    <input
        key={field.id}
        placeholder="Quantity"
        className="border-solid border-gray-300 border py-2 px-4 w-full rounded text-gray-500"
        {...register(`transactionItems.${index}.quantity`, {
        onChange: (v) => {
            setSubTotal(index, 10, 7); // time being hard coded
            return v;
        },
        })}
    />
    </div>
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={4} sm={4} md={2}>
    <div>
    <input
        key={field.id}
        placeholder="Unit Price"
        className="border-solid border-gray-300 border py-2 px-4 w-full rounded text-gray-500"
        {...register(`transactionItems.${index}.unitPrice`, {
        onChange: (v) => {
            setSubTotal(index, 11, 8); // time being hard coded
            return v;
        },
        })}
    />
    </div>
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={4} sm={4} md={3}>
    <div>
    <input
        key={field.id}
        placeholder="Total Price"
        className="border-solid border-gray-300 border py-2 px-4 w-full rounded text-gray-500"
        {...register('transactionItems.0.totalPrice')}
    />
    </div>
</Grid>
```

**Full componetn source code below :**

```
import { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from "react";
import { useForm, useFieldArray, useWatch } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import * as Yup from "yup";

export const AddSales = (props) => {
  const item = props?.item;

  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({});

  const formOptions = {
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      transactionItems: [{ quantity: "0", unitPrice: "0", totalPrice: "0" }],
    },
  };

  const { setValue } = useForm();
  const { control, register, handleSubmit, reset, watch, formState } =
    useForm(formOptions);

  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "transactionItems",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    reset(item);
  }, [item]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("fetch data");
  }, []);

  function onSubmit(data) {
    console.log("data ready to submit", data);
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} autoComplete="off">
        <Grid container rowSpacing={1} columnSpacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 3 }}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
            <label className="text-gray-600 font-medium">
              Add/Edit Sales Items
            </label>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={4} sm={4} md={2}>
            {" "}
            <label className="text-gray-600 font-medium">Quantity</label>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={4} sm={4} md={2}>
            {" "}
            <label className="text-gray-600 font-medium">Unit Price</label>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={4} sm={4} md={3}>
            {" "}
            <label className="text-gray-600 font-medium">Total Price</label>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={4} sm={4} md={2}>
            {" "}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

        {fields.map((field, index) => {
          const setSubTotal = (index, quantity, rate) => {
            const amount = parseInt(quantity) * parseInt(rate);
            setValue(`transactionItems[${index}].totalPrice`, 100);
            field.totalPrice = 200;
            console.log("index,quantity, rate");
            console.log(index, quantity, rate);
          };

          return (
            <div key={field.id}>
              <Grid
                container
                rowSpacing={1}
                columnSpacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 3 }}
              >
                <Grid item xs={4} sm={4} md={2}>
                  <div>
                    <input
                      key={field.id}
                      placeholder="Quantity"
                      className="border-solid border-gray-300 border py-2 px-4 w-full rounded text-gray-500"
                      {...register(`transactionItems.${index}.quantity`, {
                        onChange: (v) => {
                          setSubTotal(index, 10, 7); // time being hard coded
                          return v;
                        },
                      })}
                    />
                  </div>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4} sm={4} md={2}>
                  <div>
                    <input
                      key={field.id}
                      placeholder="Unit Price"
                      className="border-solid border-gray-300 border py-2 px-4 w-full rounded text-gray-500"
                      {...register(`transactionItems.${index}.unitPrice`, {
                        onChange: (v) => {
                          setSubTotal(index, 11, 8); // time being hard coded
                          return v;
                        },
                      })}
                    />
                  </div>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4} sm={4} md={3}>
                  <div>
                    <input
                      key={field.id}
                      placeholder="Total Price"
                      className="border-solid border-gray-300 border py-2 px-4 w-full rounded text-gray-500"
                      {...register("transactionItems.0.totalPrice")}
                    />
                  </div>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4} sm={4} md={1}>
                  <div>
                    {fields.length !== 1 && (
                      <button className="mr10" onClick={() => remove(index)}>
                        -
                      </button>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4} sm={4} md={1}>
                  <div>
                    {fields.length - 1 === index && (
                      <button
                        onClick={() =>
                          append({
                            quantity: "",
                            unitPrice: "",
                            totalPrice: "",
                          })
                        }
                      >
                        +
                      </button>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <Grid container rowSpacing={1} columnSpacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 3 }}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
            <label className="text-gray-600 font-medium">.</label>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={8} sm={4} md={2}>
            <div className="form-group col-5">
              <label className="text-gray-600 font-medium">Grant Total</label>
              <input
                name="grantTotal"
                type="text"
                {...register("grantTotal")}
                className="border-solid border-gray-300 border py-2 px-4 w-full rounded text-gray-500"
              />
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <div className="form-group">
          <button
            type="submit"
            disabled={formState.isSubmitting}
            className="mt-4 w-left bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-600 text-green-100 border shadow py-3 px-10 font-semibold text-md rounded"
          >
            {formState.isSubmitting && (
              <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
            )}
            Save
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```